# Fully load a subscription before the rest of the Angular component

Tags: angular

I need to load a public api that returns the public IP in order to pass a different value to my service's http post url. But I need the api response before the rest of the code is loaded. Let me show you.

**_RepService.service.ts file:** (Relevant part of it)

```
getPublicIP(): Observable<string> {
    return this._http.get<string>('https://api.ipify.org?format=json');
  }

 guardarParte(parte: NotaReparacion): Observable<JwtResponseI>{
    return this._http.post<JwtResponseI>(`${this.SERVERIP}/rep/gp`,
    parte).pipe(tap(
      (res:JwtResponseI)=>{
        if(res){console.log(res);};
        },
        error =>{console.log(error);}
    ));
  }
```

In the component's **ngOnInit** I have:

```
this._RepService.getPublicIP().subscribe(
      (response) => {
        var ip = JSON.stringify(response['ip']);
        ip = ip.replace(/"/g,""); //regex
        console.log(ip);
        if (ip =="x.x.x.x") {
          this._RepService.SERVERIP = "http://y.y.y.y:1000";
        }else{
          this._RepService.SERVERIP = "http://x.x.x.x:1000";
        }
      }
    );
```

What I try is to load first the getPublicIP on init. So the api returns my public IP and depending on this, a different IP will be used to access the data (this is because I need to access the data locally and from internet). The problem is that the response is slower than the code loading, so _RepService.SERVERIP is empty and data is not loaded. If I use a console.log inside a settimeout I can see that it loads correctly.

I'm blocked at the moment about this and I dont even know how to best approach the problem. Should I call the api in the app.component instead of inside the different components? How to assure that the api resolves the data before the components are loaded? Any other idea to properly solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid resolving service specific properties on component level and do something like this instead.

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root"
})
export class RepService {
  public get publicIP(): Promise<string> {
    return (async () => {
      if (!this._publicIP) {
        this._publicIP = await this.fetchPublicIP();
      }

      return this._publicIP;
    })();
  }

  private _publicIP: string | null = null;

  constructor(private _http: HttpClient) {}

  public guardarParte(parte: any): Observable<any> {
    return from(this.publicIP).pipe(
        switchMap(ip => this._http.post<any>(`${ip}/rep/gp`, parte))
    );
  }

  private async fetchPublicIP(): Promise<string> {
    return this._http
      .get<any>("https://api.ipify.org?format=json")
      .toPromise()
      .then(res => `http://${res.ip}`);
  }
}
```

Whit that approach you can use guardarParte(...) where ever you need and fetching publicIP is done background if needed.

Comment: You changed the function "GuardarParte" from Observable to Promise. The thing is, not in this function, but I have another that loads dynamically the data on the table thanks to the observable. I'm also suscribed to it. So once I use promise as you suggested, it errors and I can't subscribe to a promise. The way "Promise<Observable<Type>> is not a solution as well. Any solution on this?

Comment: One way is to use switchMap. See edited answer.

Comment: Might be even better to use concatMap. It will wait your promise to get resolved (completed) before subscribing to http request.